# Как узнать тип фичей полученных с помощью featuretools

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, feature-engineering

Перед генерацией фичей в featuretools можно указать тип уже существующих фичей(numeric, categorical и др). А можно ли узнать тип фичей, которые он генерирует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На англоязычном stackoverflow мне дали ответ:

`ft.dfs` во втором массиве возвращает список объектов-фичей, у которых есть поле `variable_type`, в котором хранится тип фичи